# python -m and imports in __init__.py

Tags: python, import, command-line-interface

I have a python package with the following structure

```
|-- a
    |-- b
        |-- c
           |-- dummy.py
```

where a,b,c are folders / subpackages all with a respective `__init__.py`.
Now of course I can invoke `dummy.py` as script from the command line like `python -m a.b.c.dummy` but I would like to make an *alias* in the top level `__init__.py` such that I could do `python -m a.do_this` when I write

```py
# __init__.py of a
from a.b.c import dummy as do_this
```

Unfortunately I get that "No module named do_this" which is of course true but is there no way to make this *alias*? I would like to keep the folder structure because of implementation but would like to make it easy for the users.

Comment: If you are in `a/__init__.py`, wouldn't you want `from b.c import dummy as do_this`?

Comment: No, that would not work. You would have to do `from .b.c #...` (note the dot before b). But that does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: As far as I know, `-m` requires its argument to resolve to a module *before* any of the modules are actually imported. That is, `a.b.c.dummy` works because `a/b/c/dummy.py` can be found without actually executing the contents of the containing packages.

Comment: The right thing to do is to use `setuptools` to properly install your package, one part of which can be to generate a wrapper for `a/b/c/dummy.py` automatically without the need for you to modify `a.__init__.py` explicitly.

Comment: You might want to consider a ``__main__.py``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setuptools docs https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html
answers it. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Aside that you probably do not want to use module loading as starting scripts, you can get the `python -m a.do_this` behavior with a tree like this:

```
.
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── c
    │   │   ├── dummy.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── do_this.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Assuming a `a/b/c/dummy.py` containing:

```py
print("foo")
```

And your import line in `a/do_this.py`:

```py
from a.b.c import dummy
```

This does what you asked for, but I guess it is probably not what you intended.

```sh
$ python -m a.do_this
foo
```

Anyway, I'd recommend the way that  @chepner  suggested in the comments using a proper python package `setup.py` and defining a `console_scripts` section.

The reason why your first though does not work is, that you are trying to load a module with `-m`, but your statement in `__init__.py` does not constitute a module.